# How to get min,max,avg stat values of all columns from all tables from multiple schema?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an issue with sys.dba_tab_columns view for low_value and high_value as they both showing incorrect values.

I traced back this issue to kernel where it collects the info from x$kxttstecs kernel stat table.
How can I workaround this issue by selecting min/max/avg values of all columns from multiple tables from multiple users?
Also to make it automatically updating as the DB stat views?
Can you help me with a function or either modifying somehow the kernel stat table?

I have an SQL code:

```
SELECT 
ROWNUM AS ROW_ID,
sys.dba_tab_columns.OWNER,
sys.dba_tab_columns.table_name AS TABLE_NAME, 
sys.dba_tab_columns.column_name AS COLUMN_NAME,
decode(data_type, 'NUMBER',   sys.dba_tab_columns.low_value,
                                  NULL) AS LOW_VALUE,
decode(data_type, 'NUMBER',   sys.dba_tab_columns.high_value,
                                  NULL) AS HIGH_VALUE
FROM sys.dba_tab_columns
WHERE sys.dba_tab_columns.OWNER = 'HR' OR sys.dba_tab_columns.OWNER ='XY';
```

where I get incorrect data for both LOW_VALUE and HIGH_VALUE.

```
TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | LOW_VALUE | HIGH_VALUE
DEPARTMENTS | DEPARTMENT_ID | C10B | C20347
EMPLOYEES | DEPARTMENT_ID | C10B | C2020B
JOB_HISTORY | DEPARTMENT_ID | C115 | C2020B
```

Actual values from the tables:

```
LOW_VALUE | HIGH_VALUE
10 | 270
10 | 110
20 | 110
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out just right now the answer. As the kernel stat collects this info in RAW data type, so in order to get the correct data, I needed to change the data type with UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER:

```
decode(data_type, 'NUMBER',   UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER(sys.dba_tab_columns.low_value),
                              NULL) AS LOW_VALUE,

decode(data_type, 'NUMBER',   UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_NUMBER(sys.dba_tab_columns.high_value),
                              NULL) AS HIGH_VALUE
```